# Want to know the different type of intents which we can create in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, scringo

I saw a line of code in scringo sdk which creates an Intent as below,

```
        public void run()
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(aActivity, com/scringo/features/feed/ScringoFeedActivity);
            aActivity.startActivity(intent);
        }
```

if i copy paste the same code into one of the activity.java file it is throwing error like,
com cannot be resolved to a variable,
scringo cannot be resolved to a variable and so on.

and i saw a method in Intent class as below,

```
public Intent(String action, Uri uri)
{
    throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
}
```

then why its giving error to me

Comment: You could just read [the API documentation on `Intent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html). As to the first error: `com/scringo/...` is not a `Uri`; the compiler is trying to understand it as a series of division operators but can't find the operands declared anywhere. See [these other docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html) on how to create a `Uri`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi guys after changing the code like this its working fine,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(aActivity, com.scringo.features.feed.ScringoFeedActivity.class);
```